# Which is the correct way to send @ to input in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I am using

```
email.SendKeys("myemail@gmail.com")
```

but sometimes is putting `myemail2gmail.com`, is putting `2` instead of `@`, I already did a quick research and I would like to know if this is the best solution

```
email.SendKeys("myemail" + Keys.Shift + "2" + Keys.Shift + "gmail.com");
```

The issue is in IE 11 and I am using browserstack with specflow in Visual Studio c#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used something similar than @Agent Shoulder said

```
var _element= driver.FindElement(By.Id("id"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'email@gmail.com')", _element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about people having issues with sendkeys in combination with special characters in IE and Edge browsers. Indeed, the correct way to do this is:

```
email.SendKeys("myemail@gmail.com")
```

If that does not work, you can try using Javascript as a workaround to input the email address into the field. Something like this:

```
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string script = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'arguments[1]');";
js.ExecuteScript(script, email, "dummy@user.de");
```